# Is there a way to retrive MTOM attachment from WebService using Spring?

Tags: web-services, spring, mtom

I'm using [1] to connect to Web Service and it works just fine. Now i have to retrive MTOM attachemnt from this Webservice using [1]? Because at the moment i get only empty object.

[1] http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-access